# will_paginate and "late row offset" issues

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

Maybe I am making an assumption with the topic of this question, but, here's the situation.
I have a fairly big table - 5.4 million rows - in mysql, behind my Rails 4 app.
I'm using datatables and searching. All of that is fine, but the `will_paginate` gem is killing our performance.

```
orders = Order.not_pending.where("azonref like :search or sales_channel like :search", search: "%#{params[:sSearch]}%")
orders = orders.distinct.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")

# this next line is the killer
orders = orders.page(page).per_page(per_page)
```

I believe this is because of mysql and a 'late row offset' issue, but, how to avoid this as will_paginate is generating the sql?

Comment: If you are using data tables, then you should using their data source option to handle this. Pagination on top of datatables is not a good idea as it handles pagination via its own pagination

Comment: You should check comming array of orders, is it active record or not, and array it or smth wrong

Comment: @dstull - do you have links to any examples (or care to formulate an answer to this question)? All the RoR/Datatables examples I find use will_paginate.

Answer (score 0):

Here are your options for better use of dataTables here with rails:

1. remove pagination and totally relly on use of dataTables - this has the downside of shoving everything into the dom, which will cause slow down on transfer of that data to the dom over 3mb or so.  Here is an example of using that:[specific js call - but look at entire project](https://github.com/dstull/dataTables-search/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/cars.js)
2. use data source either as an ajax source or ajax with deferred rendering.  I think the latter maybe of interest for you:

ajax source with rails(utilize the "ajax" option on dataTables initialization:

> "ajax": {
>        "url": "/sample/get_url/" + "some params",
>        "dataSrc": ''
>   }

deferred render:
https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/defer_render.html

Comment: Thanks. We can't send 300,000 rows of data to the client. We are already doing your second suggestion. The code in the question is from our Rails datatables object that is loaded via ajax. That's not the issue. The issue is the pagination. Maybe this is not a datatables question but a will_paginate question.